# has no propType for native propType - If you haven't changed this prop yourself

Tags: react-native

The full error message:

"
'BambuserPlayer' has no propType for native prop 'RCTImageView.loadingIndicator.src' of native type String

If you haven't changed this prop your self this usually means that your native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make the problem go away.
"

I am trying to make a bridge from React-native to a view in Android. I have tried to follow the instructions from the documentation [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) but it keeps given me the error. The error occurs when trying to require my BambuserPlayer.js:

```js
'use strict';

import { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { requireNativeComponent, View } from 'react-native';

var iface = {
  name: 'BambuserPlayer',
  propTypes: {
    resourceUri: PropTypes.string,
    ...View.propTypes // include the default view properties
  },
};

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTImageView', iface);
```

BambuserPlayer.java

```js
public class BambuserPlayer extends View {

    private String resourceURI;
    private String applicationID;
    private SurfaceViewWithAutoAR mSurfaceViewWithAutoAr;
    private BroadcastPlayer.Observer mObserver;
    private BroadcastPlayer mBroadcastPlayer;


    public BambuserPlayer(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.resourceURI = "sdfsdf8";
        this.applicationID = "sdffsdsdfsdfA";

        mSurfaceViewWithAutoAr = new SurfaceViewWithAutoAR(context);

        mObserver = new BroadcastPlayer.Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChange(PlayerState playerState) {
                Log.i("Broadcast Observer", "playerstate has changed and is now " + playerState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBroadcastLoaded(boolean b, int i, int i1) {
                Log.i("Broadcast Observer", "Video is now loaded. Live is " + b);
            }
        };

        mBroadcastPlayer = new BroadcastPlayer(context, resourceURI, applicationID, mSurfaceViewWithAutoAr, mObserver);

    }

    public void setResourceURI(String resourceURI) {
        this.resourceURI = resourceURI;
    }
}
```

BambuserPlayerManager.java:

```js
public class BambuserPlayerManager extends SimpleViewManager<BambuserPlayer> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "BambuserPlayer";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected BambuserPlayer createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new BambuserPlayer(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "src")
    public void setResourceURI(BambuserPlayer view, @Nullable String resourceURI) {
        view.setResourceURI(resourceURI);
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java:

```js
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new BambuserBroadcasterPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Sidecourtnative",
  "version": "6.9.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.6.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.37.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.35.0",
    "jest": "17.0.2",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

I have not changed the prop 'RCTImageView.loadingIndicator.src':
I have tried to update to react-native 0.39 but that does not help and I have tried this with running npm start --reset-cache and reinstalling all node-modules.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
requireNativeComponent('RCTImageView', ...)
```

you want

```
requireNativeComponent('BambuserPlayer', ...)
```